# using xinput to get device state

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xinput

I have a simple script to turn my keyboard of written using xinput. How can I get the current state of the device (enabled or disabled) so that when I run the script I can don't have to specify on/off, it just reverses the state?

(warning - this might turn your keyboard off; handle with care)

```
#!/bin/bash  

case "$1" in
    on)
    export DISPLAY=:0
        xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 1
    killall -q onboard 
    ;;
    off)
    onboard &> /dev/null 2>&1
    export DISPLAY=:0
    xinput set-prop 14 "Device Enabled" 0
    ;;
esac
```

now I run: `./my_keyboard on` if the keyboard is off. I would like to just run `./my_keyboard` and have it change state. There doesn't appear to be anything in the xinput [docs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xinput) (query-state does not have the property).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question: You can parse the output of this command to get the state of the device:

```
xinput list-props $DEVICE_NAME_OR_ID
```

I think the device id may vary, so I recommend using the name. I'm not sure about this though.

I wrote a small script to toggle my own touch pad:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                      

DEVICE='SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'                                              

enabled=$(xinput list-props "$DEVICE" | awk '/^\tDevice Enabled \([0-9]+\):\t[01]/ {print $NF}')
case $enabled in                                                                
  0)                                                                            
    xinput enable "$DEVICE"                                                     
    echo "$DEVICE enabled"                                                      
    ;;                                                                          
  1)                                                                            
    xinput disable "$DEVICE"                                                     
    echo "$DEVICE disabled"                                                      
    ;;                                                                          
  *)                                                                            
    echo                                                                        
    xinput list --name-only                                                     
    ;;                                                                          
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is the function to toggle "USB Keyboard"

```
function toggle-keyboard()
{
    DEVICE="USB keyboard"
    DEVID=`xinput list | grep -i $DEVICE | head -1 | cut -f2 | grep -oE '[[:digit:]]+'`
    STATE=`xinput list-props $DEVID | grep "Device Enabled" | cut -d$'\t' -f3 | tr -d '\n'`

    [ $STATE -eq 1 ] && STATE=0 || STATE=1
    xinput set-prop $DEVID "Device Enabled" $STATE
    [ $# -gt 1 ] && $(echo Changing \"$DEVICE\"State to $STATE)
}; declare -fx toggle-keyboard
```

> Usage: toggle-keyboard